# How to popup an alert when every cell in a table has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If all the cells in my table have been clicked, I want to pop up an alert.

```
<td id="1" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';">1</td>
<td id="2" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';">2</td>
<td id="3" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';">3</td>
<td id="4" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';">4</td>
<td id="5" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';">5</td>
```

(I'm making the background red so that I know it has been clicked). This is the script that I've been trying to get to work:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#1' && '#2' && '#3' && '#4' && '#5' ).click( function() {
       alert('Bingo!'); });
  });
</script>
```

If I click on cell number 5 right away, the alert pops up. What I want is when every cell is already clicked, only *then* should the alert show up.

Comment: Do you know how to select elements using jQuery?

Comment: Read the [documentation on jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) on how to do multiple selectors. Your code is just this `$('#5' ).click( function() {` based on how the AND operator works

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but I'm assuming you want to show the alert only after all five TDs have been clicked, right? Also, you don't need the inline onclick events, move those to jQuery to keep the scripts all in one place.

Comment: What you want to do is logic, there is no way with just that code to know if all of the elements have been clicked. You need to code that logic yourself. How can you do it? You need to keep track of what was clicked and than see if all of the correct things were selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to set each cell to have a red background individually on click it would be done like this and will alert after all 5 have been clicked.

```js
$('#one, #two, #three, #four, #five').click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("redbg");
    
    if($('.redbg').length == 5)
      alert('Bingo!');
});
```

```css
.redbg
{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="one">1</td>
    <td id="two">2</td>
    <td id="three">3</td>
    <td id="four">4</td>
    <td id="five">5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, as T.J. Crowder pointed in the comments below. Starting an ID with a numeric value is invalid for CSS. You can do that with with class identifiers, but not IDs. I've changed your IDs in this example.

Comment: Also note that that selector is invalid. jQuery tolerates it, but that doesn't change the fact it's invalid. In CSS, an ID selector cannot start with a digit. (IDs can -- the only restriction on an ID is that it can't have any spaces -- but not a CSS ID selector.) Probably worth calling that out and showing correct practice. (Easiest way is to just not start IDs with digits; in this case, even better to use a class instead.)

Answer (score 0):

`'#1' && '#2' && '#3' && '#4' && '#5'` is equivalent to '#5'. `&&` on strings doesn't work that way.

What you probably want to do is something like watch all of them for click, change the class on click to 'clicked', and then check that 5 cells have the 'clicked' class.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to hard code all ids for a selection; we can select HTML elements as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .bgColor {
      background-color: red;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
           $("td").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("bgColor");

        if($('.bgColor').length == 5)
          alert('Bingo!');
          });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="1">1</td>
        <td id="2">2</td>
        <td id="3">3</td>
        <td id="4">4</td>
        <td id="5">5</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Should have just been a comment on my answer.